# Odoo 8 controllers and Postman / Curl method call

Tags: curl, odoo, postman, controllers

I've created Odoo 8 controller with certain methods which can be accessed via browser (only GETs ofcourse). But I need to pass JSON object. Hence the postman. All my postman and curl calls (including GETs) get rejected by 404, while browser calls work. Does Odoo controller require some sort of browser signature? I do notice that log reports a certain database on successful. I've not found any documentation regarding how to call controllers/methods via "thirdparty" apps like postman. Any hint will be appreciated.

Best regards

Messages (unsuccessful):

> 2016-09-07 20:09:59,495 5818 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2016 >20:09:59] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 -

and successful

> db_test werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2016 20:11:24] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: Sorry for invovenience, but after I've written this message I found it. And maybe it helps someone...You need to install in interceptor (an addon for postman). Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple databases on your Odoo instance?

If so, then postman doesn't know which database to do the get request on.

To resolve this, go into you openerp-server conf file and put the following parameter in:

```
dbfitler = db_test
```

Where `db_test` is the name of the database.

Comment: No I dont have two databases yet, but this is a good info. Thank you. But I've managed to fix it if you read my answer. Yet you've struck with another issue. How does one set the db via request and then use it in code?